# Exchange 2010: Merge a mailbox between two users

Tags: exchange, mailbox

I have two users in my Exchange 2010 server where one user no longer is employed but we need access to the mails. I cannot find any function to reset the users password so my question is if it is possible to merge the users mailbox into another users?

Sincerely

Mestika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing with an Exchange server but you don't know how to reset a password in AD...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782255(WS.10).

As for merging the mailbox, use the [Export-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459227%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) and [Import-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607310%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) cmdlets.

Export Mailbox cmdlet example

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox AylaKol -FilePath \\MBX-01\PSTFileShare\Ayla_Recovered.pst
```

Import Mailbox cmdlet example

```
New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox Ayla -FilePath \\SERVER01\PSTFiles\Recovered.pst -TargetRootFolder "RecoveredFiles"
```

Answer (score 2):

Employees leave companies all the time, and I've never heard if importing their emails into another inbox.

Most companies assign someone else permission to access the inbox of the other user, and then open the mailbox in Outlook.

If you're having trouble resetting an AD password however, then perhaps you should be getting someone who knows more about AD and Exchange and how they integrate.

Answer (score 0):

We just export the "old" mailbox to a PST, then archive it.. if anyone neeeds access, we let them have a copy.. so its not stored on our server.. wasting space..

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to grant Full Access to the user on the unused mailbox. The user can then add it to it's Outlook profile and freely copy/move any needed messages between the two mailboxes.

```
Add-MailboxPermission -identity <old mailbox> -user <user> -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to access the email then take fullaccess of that mailbox first and access the mailbox through outlook or using webmail [OWA].

Or if you want to merge the data in it with another active mailbox then use my script.

https://assistworld.blogspot.com/2020/11/microsoft-exchange-mailbox-merge-script.html